# https://domain dot com to https://www.domain dot com without editing .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-status-code-301, no-www, wwwroot

I recently moved my site to HTTPS on a new host, and I'm trying to force all https non-www traffic to the https www version, since the non-www version doesn't work.

i.e forcing https:// domain .com to https:// www. domain .com

The host is a content management software that doesn't allow access to their .htaccess file, since they associate it with many sites simultaneously.

Anyone have a work around that won't mess up the site?

Comment: Perhaps you can modify httpd.conf or equivalent: https://serverfault.com/questions/190494/using-apache-rewrite-modules-without-htaccess-file

Comment: Sounds like I just make the new httpd.conf file with the same .htaccess coding, RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]          
upload it to the root directory, and wait for the host to update their Apache server. Just want to make sure that's correct, since I'm just a novice.